# FAIL Inject RemoteDev monitor into React Native debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, react-native

I am working on a React Native app and suddenly see this :

```
FAIL Inject RemoteDev monitor into React Native debugger, the file 'react-native\local-cli\server\util\debugger.html' not found.
```

when i run `npm install`.
It used to be ok before. I checked the folder `AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\util` and the `debugger.html` file is there.
Here is my `package.json` script:

```
"postinstall": "remotedev-debugger"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you fix this issue? Any solution to share?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error today after updating to the latest React Native version.

I think you need to update RemoteDev package.

For me, this involved replacing `remote-redux-devtools-on-debugger` with the latest `remotedev-rn-debugger` (https://github.com/jhen0409/remotedev-rn-debugger) as the package name had changed.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the `remotedev-rn-debugger` package.

If you use **NPM**:

`npm i remotedev-rn-debugger@latest --save-dev`

If you use **Yarn**:

`yarn add remotedev-rn-debugger@latest --dev`